# How to disable CKEditor to auto add tag 'a'

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using visual studio 2015 community version and in my program I am having issue in CKEditor 3.6.3 that it is automatically adds the 'a' tag means anchor inside the span and my dynamic page not showing properly.

My dynamic HTML code while I first adding the record in database is:

```
<div>
<a>
<span>something</span>
<span>soemthing</span>
<p>something</p>
<span>
<span>Some details</span>
</span>
</a>
<a>  
<span>View detail</span>
<span>some text</span>
<p>some text</p>
<span>
<span>Some details</span>
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

and when I am going to edit the code at that time coming HTML code in CKEditor is:

```
<div>
<a>
<span>some text</span>
<span>some text</span> </a>
<p>
<a>Some Text</a>
</p>
<a>
<span>
<span>Some details</span>
</span>
</a>
<a>some text</span>
<span>Some Text</span>
</a>
<p>
<a>some text</a>
</p>
<a>
<span>
<span>View details</span>
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

There is 'a' tag means anchor automatically add additionally by CKEditor except my own written 'a' tag, now how can I tell CKEditor to not add additional 'a' tag!

I have following entries in config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.removePlugins = 'flash,save,newpage,print,preview';
    allowedContent = true;
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    //autoParagraph = false;
    //config.protectedSource.push(/(]+>[\s|\S]*?<\/asp:[^\>]+>)|(]+\/>)/gi);
};
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false
```

Please anyone give solution as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is many ckeditor in the internet. what ckeditor are you using?

Comment: @pooria taghizadeh I am using ckeditor 3.6.3 from ckeditor.com 's provided open source editor.

Comment: Can you show the `config` for `CKEditor`?

Comment: @ParkashKumar I have update my question please look into that.

Comment: Aren't you using [allowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) in wrong way? Remove this and then try.

Comment: @ParkashKumar not solve my problem by removing allowedContent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the proper solution but for now this trick helps me for a short time.

As I noticed in my case CKEditor add 'a' tag automatically where it finds the 'p' tag.
So I just change the 'p' tag to 'pp' so CKEditor will ignore the p tag and my content will never update by CKEditor until and unless I change it.